# Android activity OnCreate is called twice

Tags: android, android-activity

I start my second activity like this :

```
Intent intentNotAuthorized = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, NotAthorized.class);
            intentNotAuthorized.putExtra("message","dummy");
            intentNotAuthorized.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intentNotAuthorized);
            finish();
```

When go back back to the first activity using :

```
      Intent intentSplash = new Intent(NotAthorized.this, SplashScreen.class);
        intentSplash.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intentSplash);
        finish();
```

when the first activity is created Oncreate was called twise

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use Fragments and just show one or the other Fragment. About your question, are you sure you don't call startActivity() twice ?

Answer (score 2):

The point is you **should not** create an intent when you want to **back** to the first activity.

the right way is just call ***finish()*** method in the second activity.

Comment: Adding a code example can help your answer to be more productive.

Comment: @RezaGhorbani your right but I think it's not really necessary in this case.